# How to define binary operator

Tags: math-operators

I'd like to declare a new binary operator. is `\DeclareMathOperator` appropriate, or is it only for unary operators? Is there a better way than `\newcommand{foo}[1]{bar}`?

Comment: `\mathbin{...}`

Comment: How about showing us (for example with an image) what operator you want to define?  Then it is much more easier to help you.

Comment: amsmath's `\DeclareMathOperator` is a (fancy!) "wrapper" for the low-level TeX command `\mathop`. Not knowing anything specific about the binary operator you have in mind, I'd say that it doesn't seem appropriate to use `\mathop` for your use case. Insteady, as @egreg has already pointed out, I'd use `\mathbin` somewhere in the argument of the `\newcommand` that defines the operator.

Comment: To a first approximation, I'd like to define binary operators that expand to \overset{\sigma}{\cdot} and \overset{\sigma}{\odot}; ultimately I'd like to make the superscript an optional parameter so that I could write A {op1} B to omit the superscript and A op1{\sigma} B to get the3 superscript.